# Insert And Retrieve Image from PostgreSQL bytea using PDO

Tags: php, image, postgresql, pdo, bytea

Im working usign PDO and PHP.

This is my table in Postgre

```
CREATE TABLE public.img
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('img_id_seq'::regclass),
  nombre bytea
)
```

When i store the file data i use this method

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=sac;user=postgres;password=insertPass");
 if(isset($_POST["insert"]))
 {
      $file = pg_escape_bytea(addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])));
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO img (nombre) VALUES (?)';
        $ISp_Res = $db->prepare($sql);
        $ISp_Res->bindParam(1, $file);
        $ISp_Res->execute();
 }
 ?>
```

And in the table the values are

```
ID  nombre
4; "\377\330\377\340\\0\020JFIF\\0\001\001\\0\\0\001\\0\001\\0\\0\377\341\\0\234Exif\\0\\0II*\\0\010\\0\\0\\0\007\\0\\0\001\003\\0\001\\0\\0\\0S\002\\0\\0\001\001\003\\0\001\\0\\0\\0\026\002\\0\\0\022\001\003\\0\001\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\02\001\002\\0\024\\0\\0\\ (...)"
```

And the form that i retrieve the values in my **table**

```
<?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM img ORDER BY id DESC";
                $db = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=sac;user=postgres;password=insertPass");
                $result = $db->prepare($query);
                $results = $result->execute();
                $results = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              foreach($results as $row) {
                echo($row['nombre']);
                  $dat= pg_unescape_bytea($row['nombre']);
                  echo "<img src='".$dat."'";
                }
 ?>
```

However when i try to retrieve the information i just get **Resource id #2** and a **Warning: pg_unescape_bytea() expects parameter 1 to be string**

This is the testView

```js
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#insert').click(function(){
           var image_name = $('#image').val();
           if(image_name == '')
           {
                alert("Please Select Image");
                return false;
           }
           else
           {
                var extension = $('#image').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)
                {
                     alert('Invalid Image File');
                     $('#image').val('');
                     return false;
                }
           }
      });
 });
 </script>
```

```html
<?php
$db = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=sac;user=postgres;password=insertPass");
 if(isset($_POST["insert"]))
 {
      $file = pg_escape_bytea(addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])));
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO img (nombre) VALUES (?)';
    $ISp_Res = $db->prepare($sql);
    $ISp_Res->bindParam(1, $file);
    $ISp_Res->execute();
 }
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
      <head>
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Insert and Display Images From Mysql Database in PHP</title>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
           <br /><br />
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">
                <h3 align="center">Insert and Display Images From Mysql Database in PHP</h3>
                <br />
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                     <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
                     <br />
                     <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-info" />
                </form>
                <br />
                <br />
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                     <tr>
                          <th>Image</th>
                     </tr>
                <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM img ORDER BY id DESC";
                $db = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=sac;user=postgres;password=insertPass");
                $result = $db->prepare($query);
                $results = $result->execute();
                $results = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              foreach($results as $row) {
                echo($row['nombre']);
                  $dat= pg_unescape_bytea($row['nombre']);
                  echo "<img src='".$dat."'";
                }
                ?>
                </table>
           </div>
      </body>
 </html>
```

Please tell me where im doing it wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't use addslashes() while inserting.

```
$target_file = '/path/to/file.jpg';
$img = fopen($target_file, 'r');
$data = fread($img, filesize($target_file));
$file  = pg_escape_bytea($data);
```

While fetching data use

```
ob_start();
fpassthru($row['nombre']);
$dat= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$dat= "data:image/*;base64," . base64_encode($dat);
echo "<img src='".$dat."'";
```